# How to not update ng-model when $scope is updated?(one way data-binding)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two forms, one for creating an account and one for logging in. They are in the same controller, as they use the same function to login.

The problem is that once I write in one of the boxes with ng-model e-mail, the other one get's updated. I don't want this, I want data only to be transmitted from the template to the $scope, not from the $scope to the template.

controller:

```
.controller('auth', function($scope, simperiumUser){
    $scope.auth = function(method){
        simperiumUser.create(method, $scope.email, $scope.password);
    }
})
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="auth" class="popup">
    <div>
        <h3>Create account</h3>
        <form ng-submit="auth('create')">
            <input ng-model="email" type="email" required placeholder="Your e-mail">
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" required placeholder="Select a password">
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form ng-submit="auth('authorize')">
            <input ng-model="email" type="email" required placeholder="Your e-mail">
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" required placeholder="Your password">
            <input type="submit" value="Log in">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this: [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)

Comment: one option is to use a directive with isolated scope

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, not sure how I should do that though.

Comment: ngBind IS a one-way data bind. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into AngularJS to handle one-way data binding from view to model.

The [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) directive handles one-way data binding from model to view.

[Bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) is very nice, but it's not for setting up data bindings. It's for rendering data once, then removing the bindings completely.

One-way data binding from multiple sources of the view to the same model sounds like a very unusual case, and might lead to some strange scenarios. At least when used like you are planning to.

Simple directive for demonstration:

```
app.directive("oneWay", function($parse) {

  return {
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      var modelSetter = $parse(tAttrs.oneWay).assign;

      return function postLink(scope, element) {

        var onChange = function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            modelSetter(scope, element.val());
          });
        };

        element.on('keyup', onChange);

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          element.off('keyup', onChange);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tDNcszN0FD7i9mXYRwpz?p=preview

If you type in the first email input, the model in the scope will change. If you then type in the second email input, the model in the scope will change again, but the previous text will remain in the first input. If you now press 'Create' next to the first input, it will call the function with the values typed in the second input. Not what a user would expect I assume.

There are of course ways to handle this. But the code will grow. The directive only uses the keyup event now, and doesn't take any of the HTML5 validation behaviors into account, like ngModel does.

The code might grow even more, and would probably not be worth it in the end.

I would recommend to stick with ngModel, use two differenct objects and pass the email and password from them directly into the `auth` function:

HTML:

```
  <form ng-submit="auth('create', create.email, create.password)">
    <input ng-model="create.email">
    <input ng-model="create.password" type="password">

  (...)

  <form ng-submit="auth('authorize', login.email, login.password)">
    <input ng-model="login.email">
    <input ng-model="login.password" type="password">
```

JS:

```
$scope.create =
{
  email: '',
  password: ''
};

$scope.login =
{
  email: '',
  password: ''
};  

$scope.auth = function(method, email, password) {
  simperiumUser.create(method, email, password);
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/VsgU8k3LYzzq7gpw6JwN?p=preview

Can even remove the `$scope.create`/`$scope.login` objects from the controller, the `$parse` service that ngModel uses will create them for you. But I kept them for clarity.